# The Change in value of prop doesn't make the child component re render

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a parent component which passdown an array prop to a child component. but as render runs before componentDidMount ,where I am setting the value to that array.. the child component recieve an empty array as prop.
I searched on net ,it seems componentWillRecieveProps Can help wiyh making child component to rr render.. but as this method is deprecated in react 16 and further. What should be the goto way of doing it.

Comment: You can use getDerivedStateFromProps instead of componentWillRecieveProps but it is not just a name change ). It's a static method that is called after a component is instantiated or before it receives new props, unlike componentWillReceiveProps.

Answer (score 1):

Only call the child component when the props value has been populated like

`this.state.arrayProp.length && <ChildComponent />`

Now when you have populated arrayProp array state in `componentDidMount`, render method will again be called after `componentDidMount`, So, now `ChildComponent` will be called with correctly populated array value.

Hope that helps!!!